# Template parameter pack expansion to one-param template

Tags: c++, templates

In the code below, I want to get function that takes `sizeof...(Ts)` elements of type int. However it seems it's not possible that way (i'm getting weird errors like "function does not take one argument" while i'm passing one arg). Why I do that? I need template function capable of taking any amount of parameters of any type and must be `constexpr` (that's why I want just ints).

```
template<typename> struct anything_is_int { using type = int; };
template<typename ...Ts>
constexpr bool f(typename anything_is_int<Ts>::type...) { return true; }
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://rextester.com/TVZEP97007). The problem must needs lie in the code you haven't shown. Show a [mcve]

Comment: Hmm.. then it must be problem with MSVC. Try it here http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual

Comment: Oh, sorry, you also pasted link to rextester :D Hm.. only difference between yours and mine code is explicit template parameters

Comment: Do you hope to somehow automatically deduce arbitrary `Ts` from a bunch of ints? Of course you need to provide template parameters explicitly.